# How to copy folder from .jar file using shell script

Tags: java, shell, jar

I have jar file ex: sample.jar  under this jar file there is a folder structure ex:  "environment/xyz.properties" and "environment/abc.properties".

My Requirement: I need to copy entire "environment" folder with all property files and past in some other (ex: /tmp/environment)location using shell script.

Please help how to do copy folder from .jar using shell script.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct
├── a
│   └── file_a.txt
├── b
│   └── file_b.txt
└── c
    └── file_c.txt
```

Create jar

```
jar cf struct.jar ./struct
```

Extract dir

```
jar xf struct.jar struct/a
```

After file is extracted you can do whatever you like:

```
jar xf struct.jar struct/a
cp -r struct/a /tmp/environment
```

Comment: Already I have jar file from that jar file I need to copy files.

Comment: So, you just extract directory: jar xf file.jar some_dir and than, you can copy it somewhere: cp -r some_dir /tmp/environment

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to copy a directory in a shell,

so you type

```
cp -R /path/to/directory /path/to/other/location/
```